# Why does "double z = 1/3" result in 0.0?

Tags: java, floating-point, division

I am trying to learn interesting behaviour of java. Please explain

```
    double z  = 1/3;
    System.out.println(z);
```

This program return 0.0 where as

```
    double z  = 1/3d;
    System.out.println(z);
```

This program prints 0.333333. What is the difference.

Comment: The first snippet does not print `0.0`, it prints `0`. This question is VERY duplicated.

Comment: No it prints 0.0. Tried it on Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is an integer division really. It divides an integer by another integer (the result of which is again an integer) and assigns the result to a double variable.

Only the second one yields a double as result.

```
integer / integer => result is integer, even though assigned to a double variable
integer or double / double => result is double
```

Answer (score 2):

first example will divide integers and assign them to your double "z", second divides doubles in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Integer/Integer is an Integer even if you assign it to a holder variable of type double.To get a double precision value,you need to do your arithmetic operations using double variables